# How to find peaks of minimal length efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have list/array of integers, call a subarray a *peak* if it goes up and then goes down. For example:

```
[5,5,4,5,4]
```

contains

```
[4,5,4]
```

which is a peak.

Also consider

```
[6,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,6]
```

which contains

```
[6,7,7,7,7,7,6]
```

which is a peak.

## The problem

Given an input list, I would like to find all the peaks contained in it of minimal length and report them. In the example above, `[5,6,7,7,7,7,7,6]` is also a peak but we remove the first element and it remains a peak so we don't report it.

So for input list:

```
L = [5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,8]
```

we would return

```
[4,5,4] and [8,9,9,8] only.
```

I am having problems devising a nice algorithm for this. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: So [4, 5, 5, 4] is considered a peak as well?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yes

Comment: What about something like [4, 5, 5, 2]? Or are the elements guaranteed to only change by 1.

Comment: @IFunball That is a peak too.  But do you have a simpler method when they only change by 1?

Comment: @IFunball Does my suggested solution suits your needs?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank you for it. I am still trying to understand it and how fast it would be. It's quite complicated!

Comment: @Anush Regarding its speed, the methods of groupby are builtin in C, so you should expect fairly good perfromance

Comment: @Anush I wrote a slightly longer solution which turns out to be faster and maybe more readable for you. You can have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `itertools`

Here is a short solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to detect peaks. The groups identifying peaks are then unpacked to yield the actual sequence.

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

l = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]

fst, mid, nxt = groupby(l), islice(groupby(l), 1, None), islice(groupby(l), 2, None)
peaks = [[f[0], *m[1], n[0]] for f, m, n in zip(fst, mid, nxt) if f[0] < m[0] > n[0]]

print(peaks)
```

#### Output

```
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 0]]
```

## Using a loop (faster)

The above solution is elegant but since three instances of `groupby` are created, the list is traversed three times.

Here is a solution using a single traversal.

```
def peaks(lst):
    first = 0
    last = 1
    while last < len(lst) - 1:
        if lst[first] < lst[last] == lst[last+1]:
            last += 1
        elif lst[first] < lst[last] > lst[last+1]:
            yield lst[first:last+2]
            first = last + 1
            last += 2
        else:
            first = last
            last += 1

l = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
print(list(peaks(l)))
```

#### Output

```
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 0]]
```

## Notes on benchmark

Upon benchmarking with `timeit`, I noticed an increase in performance of about 20% for the solution using a loop. For short lists the overhead of `groupby` could bring that number up to 40%. The benchmark was done on Python 3.6.

Comment: The function seems to be missing a return statement?

Comment: @Anush It's a generator, it [yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) the peaks. This is a good practice for when lists can be fairly long. And anyway, a generator can always be made into a list with a cast.

Comment: Thank you. Your answers are great.